# Kafka Streams groupBy without repartitioning

Tags: group-by, apache-kafka, streaming, apache-kafka-streams

Imagine a sample record like:

```
{
    "a": "string",
    "b": "string",
    "c": "string"
}
```

Field `a` is our grouping key both on producer and KStream side. Now, I need to `groupBy` based on field `b` and apply an aggregation on that. As far as I can see from [documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/23/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KStream.html#groupBy-org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KeyValueMapper-org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Grouped-), this is going to cause data redistribution.

```
// group by current key `a`
input.groupByKey().windowBy(...)

// re-key and window again based on `b` which causes data redistribution 
input.selectKey((key, value) -> value.getFieldB()).groupByKey().windowedBy(...)
```

However, due to our business logic, we already know that field `b` is correlated to `a` and it will reside on the same partition as `a`. So essentially, there is no need to redistribute data during `groupBy`.

Long story short, I need a version of `groupBy` that doesn't redistribute data.

Comment: There is no way to avoid repartitioning while using group and aggregate operation.

Comment: You could do it _manually_ using Processor API from Kafka Streams.